# Can I move a column from one mysql table to another, and replace the original column with the new id's form the new table?

Tags: mysql

My project is growing and need to expand from a single table to two.

I have posts, and each post has an author. Currently the author is a column in posts, but I have made a new table called authors. I would like to populate the new table with all unique instances of authors **and** replace the author values in the posts table with the new author ids.

What is SQL to do this?

My post table is 30k entries.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Create the new table `Authors`.

   ```
   CREATE TABLE Authors (
     author_id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
     author_name VARCHAR(20)
   );
   ```
2. Populate `Authors` with the set of distinct authors from `Posts`.

   ```
   INSERT INTO Authors (author_name) 
   SELECT DISTINCT author_name FROM Posts;
   ```
3. Add an author_id column to Posts, which references Authors.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Posts ADD COLUMN author_id INT, 
       ADD FOREIGN KEY (author_id) REFERENCES Authors(author_id);
   ```
4. Update `Posts` with the corresponding author_id values, based on an (inefficient) join based on the author_name in each table.  MySQL supports multi-table UPDATE syntax, which is not standard SQL, but it's very handy for these situations.

   ```
   UPDATE Posts JOIN Authors USING (author_name)
   SET Posts.author_id = Authors.author_id;
   ```
5. Drop the now-redundant author_name from Posts, and optionally make author_id not nullable.

   ```
   ALTER TABLE Posts DROP COLUMN author_name, MODIFY author_id INT NOT NULL;
   ```

Answer (score 2):

I would follow a process something like:

1. Create the new table, `table2`
2. Add column `table2_id` to `table1`
3. Populate(update) `table2` by selecting from `table1`, including both `table1.id` (but call it `table1_id` so you still have its own separate id) and the `table1.column` you want
4. Update `table1.table2_id` with the ids (primary keys) from `table2`
5. Drop the column `table1_id` from `table2`

Comment: i actually dont want table1.id in table 2. I want table2.id associated with any post in table1 that was created by the matching author

Comment: It gets dropped at the end.